# How to get_projects() from github repo using PyGithub?

Tags: git, github, github-api, pygithub

I'm trying to fetch projects from a github repo using PyGithub 1.58.1.

I created those projects manually in browser and I can see them.

But when I see `repo.get_projects().totalCount`, it's giving `0`.

and when I try to create a project, it says

> github.GithubException.GithubException: 410 {"message": "Projects are
> disabled for this repository", "documentation_url":
> "https://docs.github.com/v3/projects"}

But I see `repo.has_projects` returning **True**.

Same issue when using `curl` as well.

The PAT I'm using contains all the permissions in the settings page.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Could this be down to pygithub only supporting classic projects?  I don't think you can create classic projects anymore.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73268885/unable-to-create-project-in-repository-or-organisation-using-github-rest-api

Comment: @DustinWyatt Yes. That's the same response I got from github support too.

Comment: Here's some code I wrote yesterday for doing this:  https://gist.github.com/dmwyatt/efaf240205d0f48b2d593f45a721f5b9

Comment: @DustinWyatt Looks good for getting just the short information about project. Is there a way to recreate these whole projects in a new repo? and Thanks in advance btw.

Comment: I'm really just learning the API as I go along. I think you should be able to do that, but you'll have to explore the GraphQL API with their explorer tool here: https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer  It's good, but not super-intuitive either. Make sure you check out the buttons along the top side, and if you hover over keywords in the editor, you get a docs popup that you can click keywords inside of.