# Why would the github API return empty list of projects for repo/owner?

Tags: project, github-api

When I'm calling the github API through the Octokit npm package or by a simple rest call I'll get an empty array back but a 200 success.

The repo in question is private and the projects in there are private too, but this shouldn't be a problem, shouldn't it? At least I didn't see this restriction mentioned somewhere.

The endpoint I call is:

https://api.github.com/repos/myowner/myrepo/projects

Anyone any ideas?

Thanks, Felix

UPDATE:

What I call is this:

```
GET https://api.github.com/repos/me-the-owner/myrepo/projects
Accept: application/vnd.github+json
Authorization: Bearer myAllAccessClassicToken
X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28
```

Is there anything else that one should know to investigate the problem?

Comment: You must be authorized to view private repos. But without code we can't help you

Comment: @Justinas, I updated my question. With the classic token with all possible rights I should be authorized I think, but still get the empty array [].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what I'm struggling with is what JerryK mentions here:
[Unable to create project in repository or organisation using GitHub REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73268885/unable-to-create-project-in-repository-or-organisation-using-github-rest-api)

"So after looking around this is what i have found

- The API no longer supports working with the new set of Projects. It only supports classic projects
- Classic projects can no longer be created in GitHub
- Thankfully, Github provides another approach, which is GraphQL
- Using graphql you can perform all operations on the Projects, repositories etc Refer to the page https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/mutations for more information
  "

Comment: but as of now the graphql api doesn't offer something to LIST all projects, or?